# How can I show all of my posts by certain categories?

Tags: wordpress, posts

I would like to show posts of certain categories on my page only by showing 10 posts at a time with next page button. I would like this to update automatically so I don't have to manually add them each time. I would also like to have next page and previous page where it will update and show me the next 10 or previous 10.

Everything I have found on the web shows me how to do it by manually creating a page and adding 10. I would like it to just update the state every time I click next or previous instead of manually creating a page for 10 posts and then updating them. I have a lot of posts now and it's a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism that solves your problem is called **pagination**. `Wordpress` has example of how to implement one showned [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).